# Processing & OpenGL - Changing the camera position?

Tags: opengl, camera, processing

I'm doing a small project where I plot data sets onto a world. I've got the plotting done. Now I want to implement camera movement.

I have some code where if a user holds down c and drags the mouse, the camera position is changed. The thing is, I'm not sure how to calculate the camera movement from the mouse movement.

This is the camera code for the default position: camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*60.0 / 360.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

**How can I change the camera position in relation to the mouse dragging? (I've tried using mouseX and mouseY to offset the camera eye position, but it doesn't work well.)**

Comment: When you say that's "the camera code", do you mean the that's the modelview matrix? Or are you using a "camera" class/function that does some behind the scenes calculations? The simplest way to move a scene is to completely ignore the camera, and move the scene itself instead. Just add a "camera offset" to all the X,Y,Z points you are rendering, which is the opposite of where you want the "camera" to move.

Comment: I mean I want to change the variables in the processing camera() method in accordance to the mouse drag.

Answer (score 2):

If you have got *direction* vector, you can set position of your camera as follow (abstract code):

```
pos += speed * normalize( direction );
```

That's for moving forward. If you wanna move backward - just multiply your normalized direction vertor by -1. For strafing left and right, use something this:

```
pos += speed * normalize( cross_product( direction, upvector ) ); // strafing right
pos += speed * normalize( cross_product( upvector, direction ) ); // strafing left
```

Here are some notes on vector operations (from one of my "HelloWorld" applications =) ):

- **normalize( vec );** returns vec, which length equals to 1; this one "cuts" vec to needed length
- **cross_product( vec_a, vec_b );** returns vec_c, which is directed perpendicullary to vec_a and vec_b (see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) for more).

My version of **cross_product()** looks like this:

```
Vector Vector::CrossProduct(const Vector &v)
{
    double k1 = (y * v.z) - (z * v.y);
    double k2 = (z * v.x) - (x * v.z);
    double k3 = (x * v.y) - (y * v.x);

    return Vector(NumBounds(k1), NumBounds(k2), NumBounds(k3)); 
    // NumBounds(v) returns 0 when v is less than 10 ^ -8
}
```

Hope this will help =)

Answer (score 1):

I think by far the easiest thing to do would be to use the peasycam library

http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/

this library will give you access to your camera using a mouse which you can constrain in various ways as well various getters that make it easy to access information about the camera and its current state.